# WooCommerce - Hook when Cart Load on checkout

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce, cart

I have made a little plugin with only one function. This function should run when cart loads in checkout. The problem is, I am loading cart by AJAX and no action hook works on cart load by AJAX.

Do you know **any hook that works also when cart loads with AJAX**?

Alternatively, I used a filter **`woocommerce_cart_product_subtotal`**
but as it is filter, it replaces function of calculation of product subtotal.

Is there any **way I can print/echo each product's subtotal in my function?**

*(I used `WC_Cart::get_product_subtotal()` but it doesn't work. I don't know why).*

Is there anything to be initialized to used **`WC_Cart`** classes?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hook `woocommerce_cart_contents` perhaps? If you're loading `cart.php` with AJAX then most of them should work.

Comment: I applied it but subtotals not showing. I want to add function, don't want to stop original actions working. I don't know how to do that.

Comment: Is there any code I can use to print product subtotal for every product in starting of my function